# How to determine if command is executable?

Tags: c#, windows, shell

If you run command shell in default Windows installation, type `mspaint` and press Enter, Paint starts.

Is there a way to (programatically) determine, whether a command is executable?

Comment: You can run `where mspaint`, then check `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable which will be 0 if last command completed without errors (target executable was found) or 1 if with error (was not found).

Answer (score 3):

To analyze a given file, you can use the `dumpbin.exe` tool distributed as part of [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx).

Example outputs:

```
C:\>dumpbin z3.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24213.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file z3.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE


C:\>dumpbin what.com
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24213.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file what.com
what.com : warning LNK4048: Invalid format file; ignored
```